# Additional Domain Controller

Tags: networking

As it is possible to Set Addtional Domain Controller in a site , where there are only 10 to 15 users.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but what problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the question.  But you should be able to add an additional domain controller to your existing domain providing you have the proper credentials. Having a small number of users doesn't mean you can't add redundancy.

The only issues around adding another DC come around mostly obscure windows versions like Small Business Server and Windows Server Foundation.

Answer (score 0):

If you just mean adding a secondary domain controller to a domain, then yes, it's possible. We have a "backup" domain controller runnning. All of the AD info is replicated between the two.

See:
http://www.petri.co.il/how_to_install_active_directory_replica_on_windows_2003.htm

for info.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

The number of users/workstations as related to domain controllers is up to interpretation, however where I work we go with the general rule, "20+ users, stick a DC in there."

You may find some other help via this tech republic article, [here](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5208-11184-0.html?forumID=39&threadID=179362) and also by poking around this MS technet article [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc960556.aspx)